# react native google signin developer error code 10

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to use google sign in with firebase for my project. I have used it before and was successful but this time I'm unable to make it work, followed all the proper steps. Using react native 0.60.

Troubleshoot on GitHub suggests adding `signingConfigs` to build.gradle but it's already in there.
SHA Key is correct, used it in another project and worked fine, the only difference was react-native 0.59

`Create new fire base project
Choose a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) resource location
Set support email
Enable Google Auth
Added the Web Client ID from Google Auth to project config
SHA Key generated with keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore // Same key worked with other project
Placed google-services.json in app/ // Content matches the web client id from page and project config
Added all the required code to build.gradle`

I am getting no errors during build.

//main build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

//app level build.gradle

```
...
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.profitmaster"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'

    if (enableHermes) {
      def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
      debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
      releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
      implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

// app start up

```
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - native-base: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase#readme
  - react-native-google-signin: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: ...\projectPath\android\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:installDebug
11:46:22 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
11:46:22 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on '192.168.240.103:5555' : EOF hit. Read: -1
11:46:22 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Google Nexus 5 - 5.0' for app:debug
11:46:22 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device '192.168.240.103:5555'
11:46:22 D/Device: Uploading file onto device '192.168.240.103:5555'
11:46:22 D/ddms: Reading file permision of ...\projectPath\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
11:46:22 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
11:46:26 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '192.168.240.103:5555' : EOF hit. Read: -1
11:46:26 V/ddms: execute: returning
11:46:26 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
11:46:26 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '192.168.240.103:5555' : EOF hit. Read: -1
11:46:26 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 13s
65 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 62 up-to-date
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Connecting to the development server...
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that contrary to most tutorials for rn 0.60, SHA used should be from the android/app folder

`keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore projectname\android\app\debug.keystore`

Comment: Thank you from 2020. Save my day

Comment: Thank you from 2021. Saved

Comment: It's not working when i download from playstore